# How to introduce local private swfit package in the project in Xcode, just like sample app of Backyard Birds

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, swift-package

If you check the screenshot of Apple sample project of `Backyard Birds`, it has three Swift Packages which is local and private to the project only. Also, there is no `Sources` folder like other normal SPM. How can i do the same thing?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a local package from inside Xcode, File->New->Package...
- Make sure to select your project in the "Add to" picker in the file saving dialog.
- Remove the Source folder
- Right click on the package icon and select "New Folder" for each folder you want to add and then create or add source files to your folder(s).
- To make it work with the new folders instead of Source you need to edit Package.swift and add `path: "."` to the `.target` definition as can be seen in the screenshot in the question.